# Why are my link tags delayed before activating in react

Tags: reactjs

I set up a list of React Link tags in my website and when one gets clicked on, it should immediately automatically scroll down to the section the user clicks on. That works, however, for whatever reason there's about a 1-2 second delay before this action actually occurs after a click. I've been trying to figure out what is causing this but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is the NavBar component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './Navbar.css';


const Navbar = () => {

  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMenu = () => setClick(false);
  const [fix, setFix] = useState(window.scrollY >= 950);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setFixed = () => {
      setFix(window.scrollY >= 950);
    };
  
    window.addEventListener("scroll", setFixed);
  
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", setFixed);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className={fix ? 'header active' : 'header'}>
          <nav className={fix ? 'navbar fixed' : 'navbar'}>
              <div className='hamburger' onClick={handleClick}>
                  {click ? (<FaTimes size={30} style={{ color: '#ffffff' }} />)
                      : (<FaBars size={30} style={{ color: '#ffffff' }} />)}
              </div>
              <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
                  <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to="header" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} onClick={closeMenu}>Home</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to="aboutMe" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} onClick={closeMenu}>About</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to="portfolio" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} onClick={closeMenu}>Projects</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to="resume" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-100} onClick={closeMenu}>Resume</Link>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Here is the css for the NavBar component:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}

.header .navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.header .nav-menu a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header .nav-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.header .nav-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.header .nav-item a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  color: #d4af37;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-menu a.active {
  color: #d4af37;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
}

#homeLink {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:940px) {
  .header {
      max-width: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  }

  .header .navbar {
      max-width: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .hamburger {
      display: block;
  }

  .nav-menu {
      position: fixed;
      left: -100%;
      top: 90px;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      z-index: 999;
      text-align: center;
      transition: .3s;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
      left: 0;
  }

  .nav-item {
      margin: 1.5rem 0;
  }

  .header .navbar img {
      width: 150px;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you reproduce the issue as a runnable sandbox, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz to make one

Comment: Actually I literally just figured it out right now. The ```smooth={true}``` line was what slowed it down. Honestly I forgot why I even included that part to begin with so I just took it out. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Played around with it a bit more. I found that the `smooth={true}` prop in the Link tags was what slowed it down. Not entirely sure why that was the case, but removing it made my navbar work as intended.